# Kotlin Exposed - How to insert if not exists, and on conflict?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I've looked around but cannot seem to find how in the world to 'insert if not exists' or 'insert on conflict' using the Exposed SQL framework for Kotlin. I am currently writing raw SQL statements and executing them as is. I don't think I can avoid that for some cases, but I would much rather use the framework if possible. I don't see any options for either DSL or DAO syntaxs.

**Edit:**

For anyone that may come across this, Tapac's comment worked for me.

Use Table.insertIgnore() for 'insert if not exists', and an example for upsert exists at https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/FAQ#q-is-upsert-supported.

Comment: You can try to use `Table.insertIgnore` for 'insert if not exists' and `upsert` (https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/FAQ#q-is-upsert-supported) for  'insert on conflict' .

Comment: Ah thanks! I didn't really know what .insertIgnore meant when I read through the code. Works perfectly. I haven't tried the upsert yet, but I have looked at the link, I think I should fine there now. Thanks again!

Comment: @Tapac would you be able to make it an answer so maybe this question could be closed as 'answered'?

Answer (score 9):

You can try to use Table.insertIgnore for 'insert if not exists' and upsert [github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/FAQ#q-is-upsert-supported](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/FAQ#q-is-upsert-supported) for 'insert on conflict' .

Comment: why is `upsert` available when using DSL but not when using DAO